# VBA скрипт отправляет сообщение если в любой из папок outlook есть непрочитанные сообщения

Tags: vba, visual-basic, outlook

Подскажите может кто такое делал.
Есть робот который автоматически формирует пропуска на ТС. У робота есть собственный почтовый ящик в MS Outlook, на который ему по шаблону присылают данные на ТС.
Необходим скрипт который будет автоматически отправлять сообщение на определенный почтовый адрес в случае если робот перестал читать сообщения в MS outlook (Если в почтовом ящике робота есть непрочитанные сообщения значит он сломался).
Грубо говоря должна быть такая система мониторинга этого робота.
Желательно написание скрипта на VBA.
Спасибо)

UPD:
Нашел решение которое работает, но теперь необходимо что бы он срабатывал каждые 15 минут. Так же что бы он все сообщения в ящике делал прочитанными.

Готовое решение:

Sub checkForUnreadMails()
Dim objFolder, objNamespace

```
Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If objOutlook Is Nothing Then
        Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End If

Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")


Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)


If objFolder.UnReadItemCount > 1 Then   'Кол-во непрочитанных сообщений
 sendMail "script@mail.ru"     'Адрес на который будет приходить уведомление
End If
```

End Sub

Sub sendMail(address)
Dim oItem
Set oItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

```
With oItem
     .To = address
     .Subject = "Unread mails!"                        ' Тема письма
     .Body = "You have too many unread mails!"         ' Тело письма
     .Send
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Вы  не  можете написать скрипт или не понимаете как это сделать? Ну и обычно,  вся  VBA-фигня не  пишется а записывается.   Сначал а записываете макрос, то есть сами проводите операции  которые хотите видеть  в  скрипте , а затем  корректируете скрипт, тестируете скритпт, снова коректируете скрипт.

Comment: @Труфальдино не так-то все просто с "VBA-фигней". Во-первых, в Outlook нет макро-рекордера, во вторых, мало знать язык, нужно еще как минимум понимать объектную модель Outlook.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/outlook/Concepts/Getting-Started/writing-an-outlook-macro  . нет ну я не помню обьектную модель outlook, но  там в ворде или   powerpontt  все было боле  менее  понятно.  Но я  только  предложил  некое  решение,возможно  не оптимальное.  на то он  и  комментарий

Comment: @АлексейР Все верно, вот мне хотя бы найти полезные источники, основываясь на которые я бы смог постараться сделать данный скрипт, ну или может нашел бы скрипт похожий на тот что мне нужен.

Comment: Вот, например, [способ посчитать кол-во непрочитанных сообщений](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71928003/15035314). В том же вопросе есть фрагменты кода, как создать и отправить сообщение.

Comment: @АлексейР Спасибо вам)